For a selected item, get columns where value is yes, duplicate original item and update it with value of column header
I want to build a list that follows the format of the below table.  It would have circa 150 columns.
--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|------- 
ID,,,,,,,,,|Desc,,,,,,|Stream|TeamA|TeamB,,,|TeamC,,|
1,,,,,,,,,,,|Fix SOP|Input,,,|No,,,,,,,,|Yes,,,,,,,,,,,|No,,,,,,,,,|
The purpose of the list is to allow a task to be created, and then by column header - allocate it to different workflows.
The aim is for this to then copy the task, and dependant on a column value (yes/no), copy the details of the task into the same list and update the allocated TaskHolder dependant on the column headings that were 'yes'.
From that, I can then allow each TaskHolder to upload attachments, comments etc via a PowerApps edit form.
Ideally this would start as a 'For a Selected Item' flow, which then pulls the item, and either:
Filters all column headers to yes/no, and for each yes copy the task info
OR
Loop through each column and if the answer is yes, then copy the task info
If I was to do the same in VBA then the loop is more natural to me, with the task as a defined string and a loop through until the end column header count.
Is there a power automate way to do this? The end result looking like below:
--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|------- 
ID,,,,,,,,,|Desc,,,,,,|Stream|TeamA|TeamB,,,|TeamC,,|
1,,,,,,,,,,,|Fix SOP|Input,,,|No,,,,,,,,|Yes,,,,,,,,,,,|No,,,,,,,,,|
2,,,,,,,,,,,|Fix SOP|Team B|,,,,,,,,,,,,,|,,,,,,,,,,,,,|,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
Thanks
